# Gdal2tiles with tif projection failure

Tags: gdal, leaflet, tiles, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I downloaded [this .tif image](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-natural-earth-2/) of the world (small version) from Natureal Earth and tried to convert it to tiles using Gdal2tiles in OSGeo4W.

In the terminal, I used the following commmand:

```
gdal2tiles -z 0-4 -w none -s EPSG:4326 NE2_50M_SR.tif
```

and the process went smoothly, except that something appears to have gone wrong the projection. It should be noted that I'm new to both gdal and displaying tiled maps online.

When I try to use the tiles in leaflet.js, this is what I end up with. Does anyone have any ideas of what the fault might be?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully all you need to do is to set the tms option to true in Leaflet's L.tileLayer constructor. See docs [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-tms).